# Add line numbers and more characters to lines in file

Tags: python, readlines

Any help is hugely appreciated. I'm trying to take a file that has a list of lines formatted like the sample below, remove the line break and any space at the end of the line and add a line number.

This:

```
9010
9011 
9012
```

Needs to become this:

```
9010='0';9011=1';9012='2';
```

I've gotten pretty far but can't get it to remove the white spaces at the end of each number and can't get it to add the other characters. Here's my code:

```
f = open("datesfile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
lines =[each.replace('\n', '') for each in lines]
lines =[each.strip(' ') for each in lines]
f.close()
outtext = ["%s" + "=" + "\'" + "%s" + "\'" + ";" % (line,i) for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
outfile = open("variablerecord.txt","w")
outfile.writelines(str("".join(outtext)))
outfile.close()
```

But here's the error I get:

```
  File "recodevariableforR.py", line 8, in <module>
    outtext = ["%s" + "=" + "\'" + "%s" + "\'" + ";" % (line,i) for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Why wouldn't all arguments convert? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output line i.e. `line 8` should be

```
outtext = ["%s = '%s';" % (line,i) for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
```

Comment: Oh duh!! I totally overcomplicated that. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's actually outtext = ["%s= \'%s\';" % (line,i) for i, line in enumerate(lines)] but yes